# Usage "reason for the" or "reason of the"?

Tags: word-choice

When you want to know why someone is requesting for something when writing an email, which should be used?

> May I know the reason **of/for** the request?

Is there a difference between the two? Thanks.

Comment: Before you ask a question like this, google these expressions (reason for / reason of) on the internet. You should be able to find the answer yourself without difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

*X of Y* expresses a relationship - X is part of Y; Y is a "container" and X is in it.

*X for Y* expresses a purpose/answers the question *why?* - Y is X's purpose/destiny.

> May I know the reason of the request?

This sounds like the request is written on a form, and one of the lines on that form is "Reason: ______" and you want to know what that is.

> May I know the reason for the request?

This is equivalent to saying "May I know why this request was made?"

Do both arrive at the same meaning?  Yes, they are practically equivalent ... but the first one sounds much more formal as *of* implies the request was a "container" that possibly had several things that needed to be specified/known/committed before becoming an official request.

Comment: I don't much like *the first one sounds much more formal*. It doesn't sound remotely formal to me - it just sounds like something I would only normally expect from a non-native speaker. In the rare circumstances where that "reason contained within a request" meaning was significant, I'd probably expect a competent native speaker to use ***in*** rather than ***of*** anyway (perhaps specifically to *avoid* being taken for nns).

Answer (score 0):

The usual expression is **reason for**, if (as in the question) it's followed by the thing for which you are giving a reason. You might also use **reason behind**.

The first source to consult for this sort of question should be a good dictionary. Merriam-Webster's entry for [reason](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reason) has the example:

> the reason for earthquakes

There are typically two different things that might follow *reason*: either identifying what is being explained, or identifying the reason. Consider that the reason for earthquakes is a shift in the earth's tectonic plates. As already mentioned *for* is the usual way to link "reason" to what is being explained

- The reason for earthquakes is a shift in the earth's tectonic plates.

Alternatively you can use **why** with a finite clause; Merriam-Webster's example is "the real reason why he wanted me to stay". Continuing the above:

- The reason why earthquakes occur is a shift in the earth's tectonic plates.

And **behind**, although it seems more common to use this when there are multiple reasons, as in Merriam-Webster's example "the reasons behind her client's action"

- One of the reasons behind earthquakes is a shift in the earth's tectonic plates; fracking and volcanic activity may also be involved.

If you want to name the reason then you might use *of*. [Merriam-Webster gives](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/by%20reason%20of) "He was found not guilty by reason of insanity." This is common with "by reason of", but can sound a bit clunky in other contexts (usually you don't need to say "this is a reason", you just use a construct that indicates a reason, such as "because X"/"because of X"/"to X"/"for X"/"so that X"/etc).

Confusingly you can use "that" clauses in both ways. What is being explained (M-W as above):

> That’s one reason that Stalmaster earned his honorary Oscar. (*Los Angeles Times*)

What the reason is ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/by%20reason%20of)):

> I don't want to go for the simple reason that I'm very tired.